# How can I protect my computer when the only way to access the internet is though a compromised internet connection?

Tags: linux, security, firewall, repository

I access the network through a connection which is most likely compromised by a MITM attack. I can't do much about it. What steps should I take to lessen the influence of this attack. I'm especially concerned about the attacker messing with repository links and compromising my system. 
I want suggestions for hardening my system to lessen the damage of the attack.

Tips related to firewall, repository signatures, intrusion detection, honeypot etc.

**P.S: A possibly compromised connection is the only way for me to access the internet. No suggestions regarding this**

Comment: You should regard every connection through the public Internet as compromised. Under no circumstances should you ever use the public Internet assuming any transmission is safe from man-in-the-middle (MITM) listening or modification of your traffic. It is for this reason encrypted connections are frequently used: HTTPS, SSH tunnels, OpenVPN, etc. It is also for this reason that certification authentication of encrypted connections is essential practice.

Comment: Any secure SSL connection to a server with a valid certificate, where the client can check against own certs, should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

For your tapped network:

Use `SSL/TLS` and **always** check for valid certificates. If a site can't give you a valid cert then assume that it is an attacker trying to steal whatever data he can from you. (If it's valid then assume that the attacker has infiltrated the `CA` who signed the cert and is posing as the real site, trying to steal whatever data he can from you.)

As for the repositories:
Your package-manager probably uses certificates and validates them, and as such using it should be as safe as it gets.

A firewall won't help against a `MITM` attack as it is quite unrelated. (Unless you want to close all communications from your box to the outside.)

Intrusion detection won't help you against `MITM` as it only checks the contents of the communication and not the originator of the communication.

Honeypots are quite irrelevant to your situation either as they are designed to attract people who are looking for easily exploitable systems.

What you could do is look into some sort of `VPN` / encrypted tunneling solution. Like: getting a cheap ass `VPS` and setting up an `OpenVPN` on it. (Or using `TOR` although it's flaky and slow as hell.) Though be aware, that the previous rules still apply on `VPN`-s too.